# Check if record with specific value exists in firebase realtime database using HTTP REST API

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use Firebase' REST API to send HTTP operations to fetch data from my realtime database that passes some criteria. Below is a picture of how the DB is set up. An example could be fetching only the records that have animalType="Cat". Is there a way of altering the URL I use to send the GET request to include this? Something along the lines of https://database-name-38a0t.firebaseio.com/animals**?animalType=Cat**

For info: I'm building an app using react native expo.

[image: Firebase DB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `orderBy` and `equalTo` in your query params [as outlined in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#filtering-by-a-specified-child-key):

```
https://database-name.firebaseio.com/animals?orderBy="animalType"&equalTo="Cat"
```

Comment: Extra question: Do you know how to check for a specific value in either of two (or more) columns? Let's say I want to extract the records that have the value "Cat" in either the animalType or the name column.

Comment: You can only query on one child at a time, so you'd have to make two API calls for that.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to check whether multiple values are present? So for example only fetch records that have animalType="Cat" and name="Balder"? Thanks for your help Michael :)

Comment: No, again you're limited to querying based on one child field at a time. If you have more advanced querying needs, you might want to evaluate using [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) instead.